# How to add a random effect to a linear mixed effects model?

Tags: r, random, model, effect

I'm analyzing the effect of Sex, Cap.Year, Cap.Location and Spawning.Season on the number of spawning sites lake trout visit (Sites.Visited). I'm trying to add a random effect variable ("Transmitter", i.e. individual fish ID) to a linear mixed effects model. See below for sample of my data.

```
    > head(Conc, 10)
      Transmitter Sex Sites.Visited Cap.Year Cap.Location Season.Length Spawning.Season
1  A69-1601-26770   M             2     2013   Grand Isle             P            2013
2  A69-1601-26771   F             1     2013   Grand Isle             P            2013
3  A69-1601-26773   F             2     2013   Grand Isle             P            2013
4  A69-1601-26774   M             2     2013   Grand Isle             P            2013
5  A69-1601-26776   F             4     2013   Grand Isle             P            2013
6  A69-1601-26778   M             2     2013   Grand Isle             P            2013
7  A69-1601-26784   M             1     2013   Grand Isle             P            2013
8  A69-1601-26785   F             2     2013   Grand Isle             P            2013
9  A69-1601-26786   F             2     2013   Grand Isle             P            2013
10 A69-1601-26787   M             2     2013   Grand Isle             P            2013
```

Here is my model (without the random effects variable):

```
modelDDF<-glm2(Sites.Visited~ factor(Sex)+factor(Cap.Year)+factor(Spawning.Season)+factor(Cap.Location), 
               family = gaussian, Conc, weights=NULL, subset=NULL, na.action=NULL, start = NULL, 
               offset=NULL, model = TRUE, method = "glm.fit2", x = FALSE, y = TRUE, contrasts = NULL,)
```

The random effect variable I'd like to add is "Transmitter". According to everything I've read, this should work:

```
modelDDF<-glm2(Sites.Visited~ factor(Sex)+factor(Cap.Year)+factor(Spawning.Season)+factor(Cap.Location)+(1|Transmitter), 
               family = gaussian, Conc, weights=NULL, subset=NULL, na.action=NULL, start = NULL, 
               offset=NULL, model = TRUE, method = "glm.fit2", x = FALSE, y = TRUE, contrasts = NULL,)
```

But instead, I get this error:

```
Error in 1 | Transmitter : 
  operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like glm2 supports mixed effects models. Have you tried [lme4](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html)?

Comment: Try `library(lme4)` then `lmer(Sites.Visited ~ Sex + factor(Cap.Year) + factor(Spawning.Season) + Cap.Location + (1 | Transmitter), data = Conc)`

Comment: `?glm2 ... 
No documentation for ‘glm2’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??glm2’`

Comment: @David Thank you! That one worked and didn't throw an error. However, I don't know how to interpret the results. In GLM it was pretty simple (various asterisks for various levels of significant p-values). This one gives me t values and I don't know how to interpret that. Any advice?

Comment: Ah, sorry. Try package `lmerTest`, which will make `lmer` give p-values. Once you install and load it, your existing code should show p-values.